# I'd like to draw a mesh on a Nurbs surface

Tags: mesh

I am getting started on Blender so this might be a little too basic but I searched for it in both the manual and the forum and I couldn't figure it out. The thing is that I drew some intersecting Nurbs surfaces:
[image]

The point is that I would like them to have a mesh or a grid on them so the limit of each surface is more visible. The alternative would be to draw a mesh/grid and shape it this way but I'd like to know if this can be done (easily if possible).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is visualize the surface as a mesh, you can turn on Wireframe in the Viewport Overlays menu

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: No problem @FranciscoJavierOrtínFernánd Please mark the answer as correct so others can find it :) (click the tick next to the answer)